# how to add a header menu in pelican

Tags: blogs, pelican

I used pelican to build my personal blog, but I don't know how to add a header menu in my page. The default menu is "Review", I want to add a menu like "About Me ", but I don't know where to add the code to make my page work. Some examples may help me.

Answer (score 2):

> If you create a folder named pages inside the content folder, all the files in it will be used to generate static pages, such as About or Contact pages.

Cite from [Pelican Page documentation](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.5.0/content.html?highlight=navigation#pages).

In your case add `about.md` file in content/pages folder (create folder `pages` if not exist) and set article title `Title: About Me`.

Menu behaviour can be overridden on `base.html` from templates folder.